# Laravel: How to update a column value of selected records without using loop with Laravel's Eloquent/Fluent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How can we update a column value of all selected rows in a database without using loop with Laravel's Eloquent/Fluent. See below.

It works for single record:

```
$singleUser = User::where('status', '=', '0')->find(1);

$singleUser->status = '1';

$singleUser->save();
```

But it doesn't work for multiple records. It's showing `"Method save does not exist."`

```
$allUsers = User::where('status', '=', '0')->get();

$allUsers->status = '1';

$allUsers->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can execute query like this (all `status` column fields will be updated)

```
DB::table('User')->update(['status ' => 1]);
```

the other way (this query only update those records that's status is 0)

```
User::where('status', '=', 0)->update(['status' => 1])
```

Comment: I need to update records after fetching from table. Means I just need to update status only for those records which I have selected.

Comment: you have selected `where status =0`. in above answer (`User::where('status', '=', 0)->update(['status' => 1])`) this query update only those records that's `status` is `0`

Comment: I need to do some stuff (with selected users status=0) before updating users status=1 that's why I want to update just for selected users.

Comment: You can use `User::whereKey($allUsers->pluck('id'))->update(...);`.

Answer (score 0):

It updates all the rows whose status value is 0 to 1

```
User::where('status' , 0)->update(['status' => 1]);
```